# PHP - Mail script (Select element)

Tags: php, html, email

I have been working on a website recently from a website template (Puremedia). The template originally had a working contact form. It consisted of "First name", "last name", "Email" and "Subject". And then of course the message. I have now replaced the "Last name" text-box with a dropdown menu. I have done so by using the html select tags. Now my question is how I would change the php scripting so that instead of sending the message (Contact form) to One predefined email. It can send it to two different email adresses. How I would like it to be implemented would be using the dropdown menu. So for example the dropdown menu would be someling along these lines: "Choose Receiver" , "Mail 1" , "Mail 2".

And then also adding a checkbox below the message field that will send a copy to the persons own email address. - Here is my contact form code:

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="">

            <fieldset>

              <div class="row">

                  <div class="six columns mob-whole">
                    <label for="contactFname">First Name <span class="required">*</span></label>                                   
                        <input name="contactFname" type="text" id="contactFname" placeholder="First Name" value="" />                           
                  </div>

                  <div class="six columns mob-whole">   
                    <select name="mailacc">
                     <option value="1">Send til (Vælg venligst)</option>
                      <option value="2">Direktør</option>
                      <option value="3">Bogholder</option>
                    </select>                           
                  </div>                            

              </div>

              <div class="row">

                  <div class="six columns mob-whole">   
                    <label for="contactEmail">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>                                
                        <input name="contactEmail" type="text" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Email" value="" />                            
                  </div>

                  <div class="six columns mob-whole">    
                    <label for="contactSubject">Subject</label>                                
                        <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="contactSubject" placeholder="Subject"  value="" />                         
                  </div>

              </div>

              <div class="row">

                  <div class="twelve columns">
                     <label  for="contactMessage">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                     <textarea name="contactMessage"  id="contactMessage" placeholder="Your Message" rows="10" cols="50" ></textarea>
                  </div>

              </div>

              <div>
                 <button class="submit full-width">Send Message</button>
                 <div id="image-loader">
                    <img src="images/loader.gif" alt="" />
                 </div>
              </div>

            </fieldset>

        </form> <!-- /contactForm -->

        <!-- message box -->
        <div id="message-warning"></div>
        <div id="message-success">
           <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Your message was sent, thank you!<br />
            </div>

     </div> <!-- /contact-form -->
```

The PHP part:

```
<?php

// Replace this with your own email address
$siteOwnersEmail = 'mail@domain.com';


if($_POST) {

$fname = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactFname']));
$lname = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactLname']));
$email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
$subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
$contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

// Check First Name
if (strlen($fname) < 2) {
    $error['fname'] = "Please enter your first name.";
}
// Check Last Name
if (strlen($lname) < 2) {
    $error['lname'] = "Please enter your last name.";
}
// Check Email
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
    $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
}
// Check Message
if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
    $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
}
// Subject
 if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }

 // Set Name
 $name = $fname . " " . $lname;

// Set Message
$message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
$message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
$message .= "Message: <br />";
$message .= $contact_message;
$message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

 // Set From: header
$from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

// Email Headers
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


if (!$error) {

  ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
  $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
  else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }

} # end if - no validation error

else {

    $response = (isset($error['fname'])) ? $error['fname'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['lname'])) ? $error['lname'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
    $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;

    echo $response;

} # end if - there was a validation error

}

?>
```

Comment: `<select name="mailacc" multiple>` then `implode()` then `foreach`.

Comment: Make `$siteOwnersEmail` into  `$siteOwnersEmail[intval($_POST['mailacc'])]` and make your emails into an array with the appropriate values: Default: `$siteOwnersEmail[1] = 'mail@domain.com';`  `$siteOwnersEmail[2] = 'Direktør@domain.com';` and `$siteOwnersEmail[3] = 'Bogholder@domain.com';` etc. You will probably need to make your `From` email an address on your server like `'mail@your_domain.com'` and not the one from the submitted form - many mailservers reject emails now unless they track back to a valid server.

Comment: Hi. I have tried to do as you said, but now my script seems to get stuck when i hit the submit button. Do you have any idea what could have caused it to just get stuck? It just sits on the loading image after i press submit on the form.